# Capistrano deploy removes table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I use capistrano to deploy my Rails app to my VPS, but after every deploy when I visit my page I get an error. The log says:

```
I, [2014-11-04T08:20:16.659289 #12482]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 82.73.170.71 at 2014-11-04 08:20:16 -0500
I, [2014-11-04T08:20:16.662717 #12482]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
I, [2014-11-04T08:20:16.665979 #12482]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
F, [2014-11-04T08:20:16.670152 #12482] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:26:in `logged_in?'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:4:in `index'
```

I have to ssh into my VPS and go to my Rails root and run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` . In my db folder I do still have the `production.sqlite3` file, but it's empty.

My `deploy.rb`

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'movieseat'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:alucardu/movieseat.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/movieseat'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

require 'capistrano-rbenv'

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

So why is Capistrano removing my database when I deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capistrano does not touch database migrations unless it is specified by `deploy:migrate` task within your `Capfile` or by calling `bundle exec cap deploy:migrate`.

Your database 'disappears' because SQLite is simply a file in your `db` directory. Since you do not specify it should be shared among releases (to be within `shared` directory) then it just disappears and stays in previous release. Add `db/production.sqlite3` to your `linked_files` declaration.

Comment: You're correct. I've just checked the output from deploying and can't find anything in there aboute `rake migrate` or `rake create`. But it happens after the deploy, so something is going wrong.

Comment: Makes sence, but when I run it now I get the obvious error `/home/deploy/movieseat/shared/db/production.sqlite3 does not excist` . But just putting the sqlite file there won't do much because the app has no reference to use the shared sqlite file instead of the on in the db folder.

Comment: By adding some file into `linked_files`, Capistrano creates a symlink to that file. You have to create it manually there, I mean `/home/deploy/movieseat/shared/db/production.sqlite3`. For that, I would go into your `current` release, then `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create`, then `cd .. && mkdir -p shared/db && cp current/db/production.sqlite3 shared/db/production.sqlite3`

Comment: It's working great, but I don't completly understand it yet. Because `production.sqlite3` is in the `linked_files` it gets a priority over the `production.sqlite3` file that's in the `root/db` folder? Because all the data is now also going in the `shared/db/production.sqlite3` file.

Comment: You need to know how Unix symlinks work. A symlink is kind of shortcut to the original file. Notice your `current` directory is also a symlink and it points to the newest release within your `releases` directory. You can check it by `cd /home/deploy/movieseat/ && ls -la`. Result for `current` would be smth like `current -> /home/deploy/movieseat/releases/20141028175151`. The same applies to all files and directories specified within `linked_files` and `linked_dirs` and you can also confirm that in the same way.

Comment: or just "touch /home/deploy/movieseat/shared/db/production.sqlite3" and then cap production deploy or whatever you do.